# Keep only interface properties in an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this object:

```
o {a : 1, b : 2}
```

and this interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
    a : number
}
```

Now I would like to get a new object that would be an "intersection" of o and my interface:

```
o2 : {a : 1}
```

My goal is to send the object to a REST service waiting for a MyInterface object, and I don't want to send unuseful information.

Does typescript have a function for this?

Answer (score 1):

You're muddling things together here. `o` is a value, which is a different sort of thing than `MyInterface`, which is a type.

You can get a type that is an intersection of `MyInterface` and the type of `o`, using `typeof o & MyInterface`, but you can't emit type-driven value-level logic (e.g. plucking properties out of an object based on an interface).

If instead you substitute `MyInterface` with some kind of concrete value (an array of keys, a class, another object), then you can use standard JS approaches to "intersect" objects, and TypeScript should follow along.

Comment: Asad Saeeduddin, how can I do it using a class?

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a type system / polyfill language (as in it makes async / await work in ES3+).

As such, TypeScript does not provide utility functions like the one you're looking for.